# ThreeJS : WebglRenderTarget + minFilter:THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter => weird bug (not on every computer)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm front of a big and very weird problem with Three.js right now. 
I use to work with Three.js but I have no idea at all on what is happening and how to solve it.

What I'm trying to do is not even complex...

In order to show text in my movie, I would like to draw some text-characters into a canvas and then draw the canvas into a WebGLRenderTarget. The final result should look like a 16x16 grid (each cell measure 256x256 pixels).

Then, I would like to create a kind of Textfield-object containing the same amount of mesh of the amount of character I want to draw, based on my WebGLrenderTarget with the font inside it.

I made all that code on my laptop and everything worked as expected ; I got the same result on my computer BUT NOT on the computer I use at the office.

The problem looks like to come from the usage of

minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter

applyed on my WebGLRenderTarget.

If I remove that line, everything work as exected (but my text appears aliased) but if I try to use it, then the whole WebGLRenderTarget-content is very buggy (it's like the content has transparency and like the content is copy-paste on an unexepected position, and then there is some overlapping somewhere... )

Sorry, it's a bit hard to explain with words.

Let me show you what I get.

Here is what I get if I NOT USE LinearMipMapLinearFilter ; this is what I want to get

[image: Here is what I get if I NOT USE LinearMipMapLinearFilter ; this is what I want to get]

Here is what I get with LinearMipMapLinearFilter applyed on the WebGLRenderTarget

[image: Here is what I get with LinearMipMapLinearFilter applyed on the WebGLRenderTarget]

As you can see in the second picture, the "a","j","k" is written 2 times (one time in small and almost transparent, and another time in big without transparency. BUT I never draw my canvas 2 times on the WebGlRenderTarget and then it's very very weird and I really don't know what I can do.... )

In the 2 cases, it cannot be a shader-issue because I render my font-texture using a MeshBasicMaterial ; it's very straight forward.

Do someone know what is going on here ?

Any help is welcome

Thank you

EDIT :

I didn't success to reproduce a basic example with the exact same behaviour, but if you try to set minFilter on "THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter" , the renderTarget stay black while everything works as expected with THREE.LinearFilter

```
 <script>
    var fovInDegree = 45;
    var w = 512;
    var h = 512;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fovInDegree, Math.max(w,h) / Math.min(w,h), 0.1, 9999999 )
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var fovInRadian = Math.PI/180 * fovInDegree
    var focal = (Math.min(w,h)/2) * (Math.cos(fovInRadian/2) / Math.sin(fovInRadian/2));
    camera.position.set( 0, 0,focal);
    camera.aspect = Math.max(w,h) / Math.min(w,h);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true,transparent:true});
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(w,h);

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    function start(){

        //------ create a renderTarget --------
        var rttSize = 4096;
        var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(rttSize,rttSize,{
            wrapS:THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
            wrapT:THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
            magFilter:THREE.NearestFilter,
            minFilter:THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter,
            generateMipmaps:true,
            transparent:true
        })
        var rttScene = new THREE.Scene();
        var rttCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-rttSize/2,rttSize/2,rttSize/2,-rttSize/2,0,100000)

        //------- create a canvas with text in it
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = 4096;
        canvas.height = 4096;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
        context.font = "70pt Arial";
        for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
            context.fillText("Hello World !",i*50,i*150);
        }



        //------- create a mesh containing the canvas
        var tex = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
        tex.needsUpdate = true;
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(rttSize,rttSize,1,1),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:tex}));

        //------- draw the mesh inside the renderTarget
        rttScene.add(mesh);
        renderer.render(rttScene,rttCamera,renderTarget);
        renderer.setRenderTarget(null);

        //------ create another mesh containing the renderTarget.texture
        var texture = renderTarget.texture;
        var result = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512,512,1,1),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:renderTarget.texture}));

        scene.add(result);

        //------ render to screen
        renderer.render(scene,camera);


    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could it be that you have some var in the shader thats not initialized? This is the only shader difference that i can think off across different machines. I think angle will just use 0, while non-angle will show garbage. Totally a stab in the dark. I think this really needs some code or a fiddle.

Comment: Hello !
No, it cannot come from the shader part because the images I put in link was made using a basic PlaneGeometry and a MeshBasicMaterial with my WebGLRenderTarget used as "map" property of the material. 
(Actually, it also bugged into a custom shader ; I used the MeshBasicMaterial only for the debug-process)

I will try to make a jsfiddle tomorow (when I'll be at the office)

Comment: The screenshots are somewhat confusing, i can't tell if you zoomed in to the next one or if it's the exact same 1:1 shot of a canvas on a different machine.

Comment: Hello !
The second picture is the exact same object, with the same camera and the same shader (MeshBasicMaterial).

The two picture come from the same machine, but the result are weird if I set minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter on a WebGlRenderTarget (=> the second picture)